# Replace character in whole table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like ask you how I can replace 1 character in the whole table?

I want replace character which is `©` and change it to `Š`

I found : http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-replace-in-an-update-statement

I read lot of staff but i found code for replacing character only one column in whole table.. I try add names of columns to line but that does not work..

I have :

```
Column1  Column2 Column3 
 ©pple     ©og    ©ook
```

I need:

```
Column1  Column2 Column3 
 Špple     Šog    Šook
```

Thanks for any opinion

Comment: What is the datatype for `Column1, Column2, Column3`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can update multiple fields at once in your `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE dbo.authors
SET    city = replace(city, 'Salt', 'Olympic')
     , city2 = replace(city2, 'Salt', 'Olympic')
     , city3 = replace(city3, 'Salt', 'Olympic')
     , ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Column1, Column2, Column3` are of `NVARCHAR` type, then you have to prefix each string literal with `N`, like:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET Column1 = REPLACE(Column1, N'©', N'Š'),
    Column2 = REPLACE(Column2, N'©', N'Š'),
    Column3 = REPLACE(Column3, N'©', N'Š')
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/PUVT79205)

Answer (score 0):

```
Update table 
set col1=replace(col1,'©','Š' ),col2=replace(col2,'©','Š' ),col3=replace 
(col3,'©','Š' )
...colN=replace(colN,'©','Š' )
```

Answer (score 0):

While other answers ,answer your particular question..Using below method will use less Tlog and will  be more efficient particularly if your column is very large (Varchar(max),Nvarchar(max)

```
 update table
 set col1.WRITE('Š',0,1),
     col2.WRITE('Š',0,1)   and so on
```

Comment: Interesting approach. TBH I wasn't aware of this `WRITE` syntax. However, this would require each column to have this value otherwise another character will be overwritten. Also will only replace the first character, so if multiple characters occur at random places you'd probably end up doing more work to get this `WRITE` to work. If this is a one time update, I wouldn't go through the trouble. Still, thanks for this alternative approach. Seems like I still learn new things every day about SQL.

Comment: @Jens,yes it does exactly what you said,but you can use replace and substring stuff as well